# How do I prevent a module from being loaded?

Tags: 7

I am developing a custom module, from this module im trying to disable other modules (for certain reasons).

Let's say I want to disable the search module, how would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually prevent a module is enabled, implementing [hook_system_info_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_system_info_alter/7) with code similar to the following one.

```
function mymodule_system_info_alter(&$info, $file, $type) {
  if ($file == 'search' && $type == 'module') {
    $info['dependencies'] = array('module_that_does_not_exist');
  }
}
```

Then, your module should use `module_disable(array('search'))` to disable the module.

In the case you need to dynamically disable modules basing on some conditions, you can verify those conditions in `hook_system_info_alter()`, but the modules must be disabled in another hook. The reason is that `hook_system_info_alter()` is (indirectly) called from [system_rebuild_module_data()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_rebuild_module_data/7), and [module_disable()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_disable/7) calls `system_rebuild_module_data()`; that would cause a loop (`system_rebuild_module_data()` => `hook_system_info_alter()` => `module_disable()` => `system_rebuild_module_data()`).

`hook_system_info_alter()` is called for every module Drupal found.

As alternative, as Drupal 7 invokes [hook_modules_enabled()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_modules_enabled/7) when new modules are enabled, you can use the following code.

```
function mymodule_modules_enabled($modules) {
  if (in_array('search', $modules)) {
    drupal_set_message(t('mymodule is not compatible with the Search module'), 'error');
    module_disable(array('search'));
  }
}
```

Also in this case, if you need to dynamically disable modules basing on some conditions, you can verify those conditions are met in `hook_modules_enabled()`.

Comment: I got this working, but this is not exactly what I want. I want to prevent the module from being loaded, it should not become an disabled module. Im making a cookie module, when the user doesnt accept cookies, certain modules should become 'hidden' or unusable modules. So this is different per user. Is there a 'unload' function or something?

Comment: There isn't an unload function, as all Drupal does when it loads a module is to use `include_once()`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

See [module_disable](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_disable/7) and the comments therein for how to place it within a profile.install or module.install file.