# Disable admin menu for specific page

Tags: 7

Is there a way to disable the top admin menu (not default toolbar), for a particular page? I am not looking for a JS or CSS workaround, but a proper solution such that the rendering of the admin menu does not happen.

Thanks and help appreciated...

Comment: I found a function in the module called "`admin_menu_suppress`" which when called stops the rendering. But what I want now is not to load the admin menu js and css files. It will save me a lot of page load time.

Comment: If your question changed, please edit it. This site is not a forum. Comments are second-class citizens, and only content that is directly in question should be considered when answering. Your comment may get deleted without notification and no one will care.

Comment: Molot, this is not a change of question. I just found a solution that I wanted to share, but as that didnt gave me the optimized solution, hence posted it as a comment.

Comment: answers should be posted as answers, even if they aren't the best ones :)

Comment: If this is only temporarily, I use the  Admin menu hider: https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_menu_dropdown. Very handy if you do screen shots or test a site in mobile mode without having to log out first. It uses a key-press to hide. There is also the toolbar menu hider module for the default Drupal toolbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, thanks for your replies everyone. But for this specific problem, `admin_menu_suppress` actually works perfectly. Idiot that I am, previously, I was calling this function from my page tpl. Hence, the js and css were already getting included even before the content was rendered. However, when I followed the prescribed way of calling the function for each of the page callbacks where I want the admin menu to be excluded, it worked perfectly.

Check the documentation of this function for more details.

Hope this helps somebody...

Comment: You will need to mark your answer as Approved.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your admin menu to a block,  and have that block disabled on certain pages.

Answer (score 0):

The [module_load_all](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_all/7) function loads all of the enabled modules. this is its code:

```
function module_load_all($bootstrap = FALSE) {
  static $has_run = FALSE;

  if (isset($bootstrap)) {
    foreach (module_list(TRUE, $bootstrap) as $module) {
      drupal_load('module', $module);
   }
   // $has_run will be TRUE if $bootstrap is FALSE.
  $has_run = !$bootstrap;
 }
  return $has_run;
}
```

Just before the `drupal_load('module', $module);` statement check for the specific url you are looking for and the `admin-menu` module, if the condition holds skip the `drupal_laod` statement. I mean

```
function module_load_all($bootstrap = FALSE) {
  static $has_run = FALSE;

  if (isset($bootstrap)) {
    foreach (module_list(TRUE, $bootstrap) as $module) {
      if(current_path != "SPECIFIC URL" || $module!="SPECIFIC MODULE")
         drupal_load('module', $module);
   }
   // $has_run will be TRUE if $bootstrap is FALSE.
  $has_run = !$bootstrap;
 }
  return $has_run;
}
```

The [How do I prevent a module from being loaded?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/35521/how-do-i-prevent-a-module-from-being-loaded) may also be helpful

**Please note that this will require you to hack the core (modify a core source code) and is not recommended unless you have no other option.**